# Time delay circuit to reverse the rotation of DC motor when input is high

Tags: motor, 555, motor-controller, proximity-sensor, capacitive

I am trying to design a circuit to use to control a DC motor according to the output of a capacitive proximity detector.

- The circuit should turn ON the DC motor in forward direction when the hand approaches the pad (MTO pin of MTCH101 is low).
- I am going to use limit switches to stop the motor rotation when the door reaches the limit.
- When the hand becomes out of range the circuit should hold for 4 seconds, then turn the DC motor in reverse direction.
- Again another limit switch will be used to stop the motor when it reach the other limit.

I am looking to for a simple and really cheap design without using microcontrollers.

[datasheet of capacitive proximity detector](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/mtch101)

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Just use a cheap micro for the control. You'll need an h-bridge for the motor control if you want to reverse the direction.

If you really want a discreet IC design then a 555 timer one shot should work set to 4 seconds should work.

Comment: could the circuit you suggested work if used with DPDT relay?: 

https://www.circuits-diy.com/555-one-shot-timer-with-relay-at-output/

Comment: Yes, one problem that is worth mentioning is whichever scheme you use you will need to not 'slam' the motor from one direction to the other, but it depends on the motor. If it's a motor with large currents then you'll probably want an h-bridge and use a pwm scheme to ramp the motor current down slowly and then change direction and ramp up. Make sure you have diodes for voltage overshoot if the motor has a lot of back-emf